# Proving that $T_p M$ is a vector space: $+_{_{T_p M}}$.

Tags: differential-geometry

I'm following Prof. Frederic Schuller's fantastic lectures on differential geometry and I'm confused about some steps in the following proof:

---

Let $X_{\gamma,p},X_{\delta,p}\in T_p M$ for some finite dimensional manifold $M$.

Define $+: (X_{\gamma,p},X_{\delta,p})\mapsto X_{\gamma,p}+X_{\delta,p}$ where $(X_{\gamma,p}+X_{\delta,p})(f)=X_{\gamma,p}(f)+_\Bbb{R}X_{\delta,p}(f)$.

It must be shown that $X_{\gamma,p}+X_{\delta,p}$ lie in $T_p M$, that is, find a curve $\sigma$ that goes through $p$ where $X_{\sigma,p} = X_{\gamma,p}+X_{\delta,p}$ is the tangent vector to $\gamma$ at the point $p$.

Construct a curve $\sigma:= x^{-1}\circ(x\circ \gamma + x\circ \delta - x(p))$, where $(U, x)$ is a chart, with $p\in U$.

Now calculate $X_{\sigma, p}$: 
\begin{align}
X_{\sigma, p}\,f &= (f\circ \sigma)'(0)\\
 &= (f\circ (x^{-1}\circ(x\circ \gamma + x\circ \delta - x(p)))'(0)\\
 &= ((f\circ x^{-1})\circ(x\circ \gamma + x\circ \delta - x(p)))'(0)\\
 &= \partial_a \left(f\circ x^{-1}\right)({x(p)})\, \left(x^a\circ \gamma+x^a\circ \delta-x^a(p)\right)'(0)\\
 &= \partial_a \left(f\circ x^{-1}\right)({x(p)})\, \left(x^a\circ \gamma\right)'(0) + \partial_a \left(f\circ x^{-1}\right)({x(p)})\, \left(x^a\circ \delta\right)'(0) \\
 &= X_{\gamma,p}\,f+X_{\delta, p}\,f\\
\end{align}

And we're done.

---

My confusion starts on the fourth line of the calculation above, I don't see where the $\delta_a$ and $x^a$'s (the $a$-th coordinate of the chart $x$) come from. At the end too, I don't understand how the result yields $X_{\gamma,p}+X_{\delta,p}$, could someone clarify these steps?

Comment: They come from the chain rule.

Comment: There's an implicit sum over $a$ (summation convention with lower/upper indices).